# Burning CDs from iTunes

Tags: itunes

Why are my music tracks when burned to CD from iTunes thru the Playlist feature shorter than the originals?  I have tried on multiple albums all with the same result.  A song might be 4:58 in iTunes and when I burn a CD, the song is now 2:58.  There does not appear to be any logic on the difference, just that the entire song does not copy.  This does not happen with all songs, just random ones.  Typical 5-8 minutes of music is deleted from several tracks.  It is not an issue of capacity on the CD.  I am well under the limit there.

Comment: Are the original files definitely on your computer, not iTunes Match tracks which iTunes is trying to stream and burn at the same time? And have you listened to these tracks all the way through to check that there isn't actually an error reading them from disk?

Answer (score 1):

That **is** odd. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps the start/stop times of some individual songs have been changed. Try this

1. Find a song that this happened to
2. Get Info on it (right click on the song in iTunes and select Get Info)
3. Click the "options" tab near the top of the Get Info window
4. Check and see if the start and stop times have been changed. Start should be "0:00" and end should be the full length of the song in minutes and seconds.

If those times are set incorrectly the songs will be clipped/truncated when playing, creating an AAC version of the song or burning to CD.

If that is not it... well sorry I don't know